# Scroll Lock Button on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro

I cannot use my touchpad to scroll on my macbook. The arrow keys work but the touchpad will not. Is there a scroll lock button on the macbook?

Answer (score 1):

Try shift + fn + f12 for scroll lock on/off.

Comment: On the extended keyboards, it is the F14 key. Either F14 or Fn+F14.